# Pass identifier of the wire adapter dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, dynamic, wire

I wonder how to pass identifier of the wire adapter dynamically that in result we can create more generic LWC component. In example pass imported apex method dynamically to @wire adapter (smth like JS dynamic module import). Is it make sense?

Comment: That's not possible. The best you can do is write some service components and call those methods.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and nice solution idea @sfdcfox, but another idea just came into my head. Implement strategy pattern in apex and decide which method call by passed parameter value.